# Bootstrap Twitter typeahead setup not working

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter, typeahead

I am trying to set up twitter typeahead in my application.

http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/

Howevery, I don't get this thing to work. I have included the js file and have this as my input

```
<input id="hashtag_search" name="s" type="text" class="form-control typeahead tt-query tt-hint" placeholder="#hashtag" autocomplete="off" dir="auto">
```

and this as my JS:

```
$("#hashtag_search").typeahead({    


  name: 's',                                                          
  local: ['timtrueman', 'JakeHarding', 'vskarich'] 


});
```

Can anyone help? Would be great.

Thanks!

**EDIT: Now I am getting this as an output:**

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it didn't work for me either until i put your JS inside $(document).ready(); block

Comment: try adding in the css from the site. here is the link: http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/css/examples.css